# How to store contact information

Tags: c, data-structures, trie

What is the best data structure to store contact information [name , phone number]?

***Trie*** can be useful to search a phone number when name is given.
What if I want to find a persons name given his phone number. i.e. how can I find name when I know the phone number?
**Is trie efficient for such search?**

Comment: Is search the only operation you need to support?

Comment: No, apart from search, i also want easy insertion of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a trie is good. Instead of using the characters in the string as the key at each level, you can use the bits in the phone number (if you are storing them as integers). For speed reasons, you might decide to use 3 or 4 bits at a time.

This would work by having a trie struct that stores the current identity information and then an array of pointers to child trie structs.

```
struct phone_number_trie {
   struct contact_info *info;
   struct phone_number_trie *children[4]; //  or 2, 8 or 16 etc.
};
```

E.g. storing the phone number '83' (which is `1100011` in binary) in a tree where the root is `root`, you might mask the lower 2 bits (e.g. `& 3`), which are `11`, so you would recurse down into `root->children[3]` with the remaining bits of the phone number `11000` (i.e. shift it right 2). The next indices would be `0`, and then `10` and then `1` (so you would be pointing at `root->children[3]->children[0]->children[2]->children[1]`). At this point you have no set bits left in your phone number, so you've found the right place to insert.

(You could also consider using a [Patricia trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_trie), but this is significantly harder to implement.)

Comment: I have read Patricia tree. But this doesn't solve my problem. My problem is what to do when the user wants to search by phone number & also search by name.

Comment: (Patricia trie is only if you want very fast look-ups (it is much harder to implement than a normal trie).) You should just have a trie that maps names to `contact_info`s and one that maps phone number to `contact_info`s (i.e. two tries), so when you insert, you allocate your `contact_info` struct and set the appropriate pointer in each of the tries to point to that struct, and then you can just search in the appropriate trie. (Does that answer your question?)

Comment: Yeah.sure..But don't you think that we will end up with storing the same data twice? Do we have some way to reduce the space?

Comment: Not obviously, at least not in a way that maintains the fast look-ups and inserts.